# CentOS Create User With No Password, Only Public Key Auth

Tags: linux, centos, public-key

How can I create a user on CentOS 5.6, which cannot login with a password. I.E. they can only login and SSH using public key authentication.

```
 useradd myuser -d /their-home-dir
```

Will that do it, without calling passwd?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, that will do it but you should add some keys to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of course.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to enforce only pubkey auth, then you need to modify your /etc/ssh/sshd_config , and set

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Comment: I've done this, and `root` user can get in without password, but another sudo/wheel user cannot. Despite putting a key in the command, that user still needs a password. Can I disable a password and enable ONLY key login for that other sudo/wheel user too?